# Galen framework for Android Apps

Tags: android, selenium-webdriver, appium, galen

Wanted to know like there is Galen test framework for web-page visual rendering test on the multiple devices such as mobile, tablet and desktop etc with Appium.

Is there any support from Galen framework on the Android apps also (Visual Android Layout comparison with given specs as input) ?

And what could be the inputs( say :welcomePage.spec as input to the html pages) if the Android apps are supported ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used galen-rainbow dependency for the layout comparison of Android apps

Answer (score 0):

you can use it together with Appium, see this example: https://github.com/saikrishna321/Galen-TestNG-Appium-Maven

Comment: Its only for the firefox or some browser not for the android apps, I tried connecting android device with all the browser opening some webUrl(Via Appium). My question is whether any provision is there for the android apps layout comparison with defined specs

Comment: so did you have an hybrid app with HTML pages you want to verify?

Comment: Is that Possible for plain android app ? No I need it for Normal android app too

Comment: would not work, as the framework is used for HTML layouts